# Mex compiler not supporting vc++ 2015 but online it says that it does

Tags: matlab, mex

> The current MEX compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional (C)' is not supported.
>   Use mex -setup to select a supported compiler.

**Output from `mex -setup`**

> MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional' for C++ language compilation.

I am not quite sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: 2015b. Online it says I should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ compilers need to be configured separately:

```
>> mex -setup C
```

and

```
>> mex -setup CPP
```

There's even one for Fortran if you have a [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/) (`mex -setup Fortran`).